# Названия СМИ: правда, известия, вести, ведомости

Tags: этимология

Названия средств массовой информации "Правда", "Известия", "Вести", "Ведомости" имеют единое происхождение от корня "вед"?

Answer (score 1):

Слова известие, весть, ведомость являются родственными. Вести, ведомость произошли от глагола ведать, слово правда - от прилагательного правый, далее от праслав. *prāvъ

Comment: Случаем не наоборот? Правь (как управляй) от Право (гражданское, уголовное и пр.), Право от Правый (наше дело "правое"), Правильный. Правый от Праведный.

Comment: Да, имелось ввиду, что правда от правый, а оно от правь, др.-русск. правъ «прямой, правильный, невиновный» (Словарь Фасмера)